# Drush + Cygwin PHP fatal errors

Tags: php, drupal, cygwin, drush

I have had to re-install / update Cygwin on Windows 8.1, and I have some how broken Drush on my Drupal 7 sites.

Previously I followed this guide [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1432756) So I have tried to do a clean install of drush, and noticed that you can now install drush via pear.

```
pear channel-discover pear.drush.org
pear install drush/drush
```

So in my home directory :

```
$ drush --version
 Drush Version   :  6.2.0
```

That seems to work, but when I go into my directory where my Drupal web site is, I am getting PHP fatal errors, it is like the PATH or something is broken when I run drush from there :

```
$ cd /cygdrive/c/websites/www.mywebsite.com
$ drush
require_once(c:/websites/www.mywebsite.com/modules/system/system.module): failed to open stream: No such file or directory drupal.inc:21           [warning]
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'c:/websites/www.mywebsite.com/modules/system/system.module' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/pear/drush/includes/drupal.inc on line 21
require_once(c:/websites/www.mywebsite.com/modules/system/system.module): failed to open stream: No such file or directory drupal.inc:21           [warning]
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'c:/websites/www.mywebsite.com/modules/system/system.module' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/pear/drush/includes/drupal.inc on line 21
```

My Current set up is :

- Windows 8.1
- Cygwin
- Drupal 7
- For PHP I am using WAMP, but PHP is working in Cygwin

.

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.16 (cli) (built: Aug 24 2014 01:12:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Have you tried adding symlinks to resolve the include errors?

Answer (score 0):

When using Cygwin's version of PHP, the "require" statement does not recognize path names which start with a drive letter. Thus `require 'C:\path-to-file'` will generally fail. Internally, it sees the 'C:' as a relative path and appends it to the default directory rather than treating it as an absolute path.

If you rewrite the require statements to use `__DIR__`, then things usually work.

`require __DIR__ . '/modules/system/system.module';`